# NSURLSession downloadTaskWithResumeData giving error after relaunch app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I have created a download task. I have cancelled the task in my application with `cancelByProducingResumeData` and saved to disk. When user relaunch application and click on resume button I have again started the download task by `self.downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithResumeData:resumableData];`. But this gives error.

`Invalid resume data for background download. Background downloads must use http or https and must download to an accessible file`

**EDIT**: I have verified the `tmp` directory on simulator contains the downloadData but not able to access that.

Comment: Sounds *exactly* like this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360750/nsurlsession-with-invalid-resume-data

Comment: @Petesh yes I have already seen that but that is not solution.

Comment: I have verified `tmp` contains the data after relaunching.

Comment: Exactly @Petesh, it clears all cached data, but before doing anything you can check for data existence `recommended by Apple`. Please refer [Stackoverflow Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895853/how-can-i-check-that-an-nsdata-blob-is-valid-as-resumedata-for-an-nsurlsessiondo) for more details.

Comment: But it's corrupting every time on relaunching and I have checked the path is not my application temp directory.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the application **link on the tmp** file in resuminData **is not valid**. **Change the field**-"NSURLSessionResumeInfoLocalPath" in resuminData, to the correct path of the tmp file.

use:

```
NSMutableDictionary* resumeDictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:resumingData options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:NULL error:&error];
...
NSString* badFilePath = [resumeDictionary objectForKey:@"NSURLSessionResumeInfoLocalPath"];
...
[resumeDictionary setObject:trueTmpfile forKey:@"NSURLSessionResumeInfoLocalPath"];
...
NSData* newResumingData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:resumeDictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```