# Why is URLSession not resuming on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsurlsession

In my iOS download manager

RCDownload is an object that holds title, url, download state and resume data location of a download

I have a block variable called defaultSession which looks like this:

```
lazy var defaultSession: URLSession = {

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "RCBackgroundDownloader")
        configuration.isDiscretionary = false
        configuration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        return session
    }()
```

My app is able to pause and resume downloads

And my resume function looks like this:

```
func resume(download: RCDownload) {

        var data: Data!

        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: download.getResumeDataURL())
        } catch {}

        download.downloadState = downloadStatus.downloading

        if data != nil {
            download.downloadTask = self.defaultSession.downloadTask(withResumeData: data)
            download.downloadTask?.resume()
        } else {
            download.downloadTask = self.defaultSession.downloadTask(with: download.downloadURL)
            download.downloadTask?.resume()
        }

    }
```

This code works perfectly on iOS 9 but on iOS 10 it does not resume when I kill my app and reopen it no errors are appearing though (reminder: it is working perfectly on iOS 9), I am confused is there any explanation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is in iOS 10, Apple has to fix it. They have fixed it for 10.2 version though, according to this [thread on Apple's forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63585).

You can also look into this [Stackoverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346231/resume-nsurlsession-on-ios10). They have provided the solution with details.

Comment: Finally I have an explanation I have been trying to solve it since iOS 10.0. Thanks man.